# Webpack errors related to material-ui

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm cloning my friend's repo on github

[https://github.com/feijihn/todolist_react](http://git@github.com:feijihn/todolist_react.git)

with web app built on node.js + react.js + material.ui

then i'm installing requirements with npm:

```
npm i -S -d
```

after that i launch server

```
node server.js
```

and everything works perfectly, but then i make some changes and try to pack a new bundle.js thru webpack it gives me this error:

```
webpack --display-detailed-errors
Hash: 396f0bfb9d565b6f60f0
Version: webpack 1.12.12
Time: 1294ms
   + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./public/scripts/index.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/ignatif/todolist_react/public/scripts/index.jsx: Unexpected token (91:3)
89 |  render: function()  {                                                                            
90 |          return (
91 |                  <Paper className="paperE" zDepth={5}>
   |    ^
92 |                          <AppBar
93 |                                  title="Just To-Do. No shit"
94 |                                  iconClassNameRight="muidocs- icovigation-expand-more"/>
at Parser.pp.raise (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1425:13)
at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2907:8)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:754:12)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:509:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:489:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:420:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:402:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:365:19)
at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:827:26)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:713:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:509:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:489:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:420:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:402:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:365:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExpression (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:329:19)
at Parser.pp.parseReturnStatement (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2106:26)
at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1894:19)
at Parser.pp.parseBlockBody (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2294:21)
at Parser.pp.parseBlock (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2275:8)
at Parser.pp.parseFunctionBody (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1130:22)
at Parser.pp.parseFunction (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2406:8)
at Parser.pp.parseFunctionExpression (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:764:17)
at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:726:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:509:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:489:19)
at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:420:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:402:19)
at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules/babylon/index.js:365:19)
at Parser.pp.parseObjPropValue (/home/ignatif/todolist_react/node_modules /babylon/index.js:1021:99)
```

I have material-ui installed and i can't find any dependency problems myself.
My friend's webpack packs everything nicely and don't give any error. What can cause this?

Comment: I cloned the repo, then npm install, the wepack to compile the files and finally, node server.js. I doesn't have the error you describe

Answer (score 0):

The repo you provided work if you type :

1. `npm install`
2. `webpack`
3. `node server.js`

Comment: i'm happy this works to you, it works to everyone, but the PROBLEM is that it doesn't work to me.

Comment: which version of node and npm, do you use ?

Comment: but then i make some changes and try to pack a new bundle.js thru webpack it gives me this error: .. What kind of changes ?

Comment: @user3443399 i can't repack even without any changes. node v5.5.0 npm v3.3.12

Comment: I tried with the same node version as you and it works again it's really weird...